# Erro ao chamar um serviço através do ServiceClient em C#

Tags: c#, web-service, visual-studio, wcf

Tenho uma parte no projeto (MVC que liga à BD através de web services) da minha empresa que chama serviços WCF desta forma:

```
public static ReturnType CallWebMethod<TService, ReturnType>(String endpointConfigurationName, String myMethod, object[] parameters = null)
    where TService : class
    {
        var client = new ServiceClient<TService>(endpointConfigurationName);

        // Get a type from the class 
        Type type = client.Proxy.GetType();

        // Retrieve the method you are looking for
        MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(myMethod);

        ReturnType result;
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            // Invoke the method on the instance we created above
            result = (ReturnType)methodInfo.Invoke(client.Proxy, parameters);
            if (client.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                client.Close();
                success = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success)
                client.Abort();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Eu baixei o projeto do repositório (o projeto no repositório é a versão final que está em produção) e tenho recebido o erro `Object Reference not set to an instance of an object` por causa do `methodInfo`, que está null. Supostamente eu mando o nome do serviço e o nome do método,  os dois válidos (funcionam em produção), mas ele não consegue encontra-los.

Faço a chamada assim:

```
return ServicesHelper.CallWebMethod<BusinessServicesImplementation.IBusinessOportunitiesService, bool>
             ("BusinessServicesImplementation.BusinessOportunitiesService", "SyncUpGpc_Aiccopn_Users_and_Companies", par);
```

O que posso fazer para tentar identificar o problema?

Comment: Como está chamando isto?

Comment: já editei e adicionei a chamada, a variável `par` é irrelevante, mas trata-se de um array de objetos

Comment: O problema está em `SyncUpGpc_Aiccopn_Users_and_Companies`. Sei que não é culpa sua, mas isto é uma gambiarra enorme, eu nem usaria este código.

Comment: Essa classe é para chamar qualquer serviço que esteja no contract do seu WCF ???

Comment: o que tem de errado com esse código?

Comment: @JulioSoares sim, basicamente passo o nome do serviço e depois o método, mas quando não encontra dá berro!

Comment: Honestamente @ihavenokia, prefiro trabalhar com os Clients diretamente na minha aplicação e independentes... Acho essa utilização de reflection um tanto desnecessária visto que chamando meus serviços diretamente eu já tenho as definições e os tipos que irão ser retornados... tem um processamento desnecessário nessa classe

Comment: Vou transformar o método para que chame diretamente o web service, em vez de o estar a construir, isso, em princípio, vai resolver o meu problema